# Access app.js variables in routes but without global express

Tags: node.js, express

This is my config in app.js:

```
var express = require('express')
, routes = require('./routes')
, user = require('./routes/user')
, http = require('http')
, path = require('path')
, Server = mongo.Server
, Db = mongo.Db;
, mongo = require('mongodb');
, BSON = mongo.BSONPure;


var app = express();
var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true, });
var db = new Db('tasksdb', server); //i need to remove this "var" to access db in routes


db.open(function(err, db) {
if(!err) {
 console.log("Connected to 'tasksdb' database");
 db.collection('tasks', {safe:true}, function(err, collection) {
   if (err) {
     console.log("The 'tasks' collection doesn't exist. Creating it with sample data...");
     populateDB();
   }
 });
}
});

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/tasks', routes.getAllTasks);
```

In routes/index.js i have:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};

exports.getAllTasks = function (req, res) {

db.collection( 'tasks', function ( err, collection ){ //this "db" is not accessible unless i remove "var" from db in app.js

    collection.find().toArray( function ( err, items ) {

        res.send(items);

    })

})
};
```

it is of course not working unless i remove "var" from  "db" in app.js, then it became global and i can access it in routes, but i don't want globals in my code and don't want to move controllers actions to app.js file. How to fix it ???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand. Isn't `db` global with or without `var` ( it looks like a global scope for me )? Besides, why don't you want it to be global? That's a good example of using globals.

But it won't get shared between files. You have to add it to exports. Try this:

**app.js**

```
exports.db = db;
```

**routes/index.js**

```
var db = require("app").db;
```

The other way is to add `db` to every handler like this:

**app.js**

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/tasks', routes.getAllTasks);
```

Then it should be available in any route as `req.db`.

Comment: it actually is but its global to file when it is with var - when I remove it - becames global and avaliable to all files. Thanks for help - it works wery good :)

Comment: How to I get anyObj from routes/index.js ?

    //app.js

    const app = express()
    const routes = require('./routes')
    app.use('/', routes)

    app.set('anyObj', {})


    // routes/index.js
    const express = require('express')
    const router = express.Router()

    const users = require('./users')
    router.use('/api/users', users)